# Why can't I initialize the member variable inside the new?

Tags: perl, class, object, perl-module

I am trying to undestand OO in Perl. I made the following trivial class:

```
#/usr/bin/perl  
package Tools::Util;  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $var;  

sub new {  
    my ($class, $arg) = @_;   
    my $small_class = {  
        var => $arg,  
    };  
    return bless $small_class;    
}  

sub print_object {  
    print "var = $var\n";  #this is line 20   
}  

1;
```

And this is a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Tools::Util;  

my $test_object = new Tools::Util("Some sentence");  
$test_object->print_object();  
use Data::Dumper;  
print Dumper($test_object);
```

The result I get is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $var in concatenation (.) or string at Tools/Util.pm line 20.   
var =   
$VAR1 = bless( {  
                 'var' => 'Some sentence'   
               }, 'Tools::Util' );
```

I can not understand this. I thought that objects in Perl are hashes and so I could access/initialize the member variables using the same names without a `$`. Why in this case the `$var` is not initialized but the hash that I Dump contains the value?
How should I use/initialize/handle member variables and what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You almost certainly want `bless $obj, $class` rather than just `bless $obj`.

Comment: sidenote, `bless $small_class, $class;` is better for inheritance, and  `Tools::Util->new("Some sentence")` is preferred over indirect syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$var` is lexical class variable, and undefined in your example.

You probably want:

```
sub print_object {  
    my $self = shift;
    print "var = $self->{var}\n";
}
```

Comment: But I want to initialize `$var` inside the constructor `new`. Isn't `$var` a member variable? Is it not the same as `$self->{var}`?

Comment: they are not same; first is plain lexical and second is key inside `$test_object` hashref/object.

Comment: To be honest I am not really sure I understand what you mean by "plain lexical".I think I am thinking more in terms of other languages

Comment: lexical is local variable with limited scope, variable which is not global

Answer (score 3):

Perl doesn't handle object methods in quite the same way that you're used to.

Are you familiar with the implicit `this` argument that many object-oriented languages use? If not, now would be a great time to read up on it.

Here's a five-second introduction that glosses over the details:

```
//pretend C++

//this function signature
MyClass::MyFunction(int x);

//is actually more like the following
MyClass::MyFunction(MyClass this, int x);
```

When you access instance members of the class, `my_var` is equivalent to `this.my_var`.

In Perl, you get to do this manually! The variable `$var` is *not* equivalent to `$self->{var}`.

Your blessed object is actually a hash reference, and can be accessed as such. When you call `$test_object->print_object()`, the sub gets the value of `$test_object` as its first argument. Most Perl programmers handle this like so:

```
sub my_method {
    my $self = shift; #shift first argument off of @_
    print $self->{field};
}
```

With that in mind, you should probably rewrite your `print_object` sub to match [mpapec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458785/why-cant-i-initialize-the-member-variable-inside-the-new/19458810#19458810).

Further reading: [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html), [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html)